# ReactNative GeoLocation with another asynchronous api call inside not working

Tags: api, asynchronous, react-native, geolocation

I am using geolocation to get the current coordinates (latitude and longitude). When the coordinates are available, I want to be able to make an API call using the returned coordinates. 
However, the API call is not executing right for some reason. What is the right way to make the API call right after geolocation has returned the coordinates ?
Here is the code :

```
const that = this;
//Getting the current location using the geolocation API
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  (position) => {
    this.setState({
      latitude: position.coords.latitude,
      longitude: position.coords.longitude,
      error: null
    });


 //Here is the API call to be executed after the coordinates are returned and state is set for the latitude and longitude

     const url = 'http://sewoa-easy-breezy-home-number-api-us1.smx.online/api/v1/houses/number?latitude=' + that.state.latitude
       + '&longitude=' + that.state.longitude;
     axios.get(url).then(function (response) {
       if (response.data) {
         Actions.viewHouseNumber({ houseNumber: response.data.number });
       } else {
         Actions.houseNotFound({ latitude: that.state.latitude, longitude: that.state.longitude });
       }
     }).catch(() => {
         // The request was made, but the server responded with a status code
         // that falls out of the range of 2xx
         if (that.state.latitude && that.state.longitude) {
           Actions.houseNotFound({ latitude: that.state.latitude, longitude: that.state.longitude });
         }
         else {
           Actions.error({ message: 'connection_error'});
         }
       });
  },
(error) => {
Actions.error({ message: 'gps_error' });
return;
},
{ enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 },
)
```

Both navigation.getCurrentPostion and axios.get  methods used here work on a separately. However now that the API call is inside the gelocation.getCurrentPosition method, the whole thing is not working. Any idea on how I could solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

In React, setState is *asynchronous*. This means it is not executed instantly, and it's going to wait until the next update cycle to be actually executed. This is often invisible to the user, but this means `that.state.latitude` and `that.state.longitude` are probably undefined. Try `console.log(that.state.latitude, that.state.longitude)` right after your setState call.

The solution : setState accepts a callback as second parameter. You could put all the parts of code that depend on the new values of the state inside said callback. This would ensure the state has been updated before running these lines.

This could look like this (assuming the snippet you posted goes inside the componentWillMount method of your component) :

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  fetchHouseNumber = () => {
    const url = 'http://sewoa-easy-breezy-home-number-api-us1.smx.online/api/v1/houses/number?latitude=' + this.state.latitude
       + '&longitude=' + this.state.longitude;
    axios.get(url).then(function (response) {
      if (response.data) {
        Actions.viewHouseNumber({ houseNumber: response.data.number });
      } else {
        Actions.houseNotFound({ latitude: this.state.latitude, longitude: this.state.longitude });
      }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    //Getting the current location using the geolocation API
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        this.setState({
          latitude: position.coords.latitude,
          longitude: position.coords.longitude,
          error: null,
        }, () => this.fetchHouseNumber()); // The callback I'm talking about
      }
      (error) => {
        Actions.error({ message: 'gps_error' });
      },
      {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 20000,
        maximumAge: 1000
      })
  }
}
```

Side note : why are you using `that` instead of this ? Since you are working with arrow functions, you don't need to secure the value of `this`. Plus, I don't see `that` being assigned in your snippet. Couldn't your issue come from this?

### Edit : performance

As was noted in the comments, using a callback on setState could be expensive. If you want to fire your API call ASAP, before waiting for the setState callback to be fired, here is how you could do it :

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  fetchHouseNumber = (latitude, longitude) => {
    const url = 'http://sewoa-easy-breezy-home-number-api-us1.smx.online/api/v1/houses/number?latitude=' + latitude
       + '&longitude=' + longitude;
    axios.get(url).then(function (response) {
      if (response.data) {
        Actions.viewHouseNumber({ houseNumber: response.data.number });
      } else {
        Actions.houseNotFound({ latitude, longitude });
      }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    //Getting the current location using the geolocation API
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        const { latitude, longitude } = position.coords; // destructuring assignment
        this.fetchHouseNumber(latitude, longitude);
        this.setState({
          latitude, // object property shorthand
          longitude,
          error: null
        });
      }
      (error) => {
        Actions.error({ message: 'gps_error' });
      },
      {
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 20000,
        maximumAge: 1000
      })
  }
}
```

That way, you're firing the callback as soon as the geolocation data is available, but still putting the geolocation data in the state if it is neeeded elsewhere in the component (if it's not, you can just drop the setState part...).

Comment: that is an upper scope variable I forgot to copy  in but I just edited it. How would you exactly write the setState method in this case (code-wise) ?

Comment: I just added a snippet. Sorry I figured later that my explanation was quite abstract

Comment: However `that` is probably not needed, since you are working with arrow functions. Using only `this` and declaring only arrow functions (when possible) is often much easier than carrying around `self`, `that` or `_this` or whatever when you need to access your component's scope inside of callbacks.

Comment: Although this answer shows a good way to use `setState` properly, you could just use the values from the `position` object rather than trying to read them from state. This would help on not waiting for the state to set for making the API call. Could be milliseconds in difference but that is another option to think.

Comment: @bennygenel is perfectly right. I'm editing the snippet taking this performance concern into account.

Comment: Which one ? The first one, or the refactor ? Can you elaborate ?